# how do i make an irregular shape with python idle graphics

Tags: python

```
pt1 = Point(280,49)
pt2 = Point(279,62)
pt3 = Point(276,86)
pt4 = Point(274,114)
pt5 = Point(273,126)
pt6 = Point(271,153)
pt7 = Point(269,166)
pt8 = Point(268,179)
pt9 = Point(267,192)
pt10 = Point(266,206)
pt11 = Point(265,213)
pt12 = Point(264,223)
pt13 = Point(264,230)
pt14 = Point(262,238)
pt15 = Point(256,238)
pt16 = Point(244,238)
pt17 = Point(235,239)
pt18 = Point(226,238)
pt19 = Point(223,236)
pt20 = Point(226,222)

ferb = Polygon     (pt1,pt2,pt3,pt4,pt5,pt6,pt7,pt8,pt9,pt10,pt11,pt12,pt13,pt14,pt15,pt16,pt17,pt18,pt19,pt20).
```

This is my code and I need I way to rewrite this using loops in python. I have to use either for or while loop, oh and conditional statements(if and elif) if neccessary

Comment: Since there's no consistency nor a pattern, there's no way to do it in a loop...

Comment: Why not use a list of coordinates?